# catching DOm elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi Guys I need help with catching a img tab in side of the p tag

this is my html

```
<p>
  <img style="max-width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: 
     auto; display: block;" 
     src="../content_platform_node/content_primitive/51e4c3e29306e2581000000a/blob"
     alt="" data-lscp-resource-mimetype="image/jpeg" 
     data-lscp-resource-id="51e4c3e29306e2581000000a" />
 </p>
```

what I need is to wrap the img tab with a  tag instead of p tag , note this is not pre-generated its user input content therefore I need to do this with jquery or javascript

help needed

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
var parent = $('img').parent();
parent.wrap('<div />').contents().unwrap()
```

and the `div` can be any other tag

Comment: if this is a html string say the this whole html block is content , How do it say cont - p -children ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = $('img[data-lscp-resource-id="51e4c3e29306e2581000000a"]');
image.parent('p').replaceWith($('<a></a>').html(image));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px8wF/)

**EDIT**: raw js:

```
var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
var oldParent = image.parentNode;

var newParent = document.createElement('a');
newParent.appendChild(image);
oldParent.parentNode.appendChild(newParent);
oldParent.parentNode.removeChild(oldParent);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vJpF/)